# Java Reflection Casting Method ReturnType

Tags: java, generics, reflection, casting

To give some background, I am creating a small dependency injector and running into problems casting method invocations back into their return types. A minimal example is:

```
public class MinimalExample {
    public static <T> void invokeMethod(Class<T> aClass) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Optional<Method> myOptMethod = resolveMethod(aClass);
        if (myOptMethod.isPresent()) {
            Method myMethod = myOptMethod.get();
            Object myInstance = myMethod.invoke(myMethod);
            doSomething(myMethod.getReturnType(), myMethod.getReturnType().cast(myInstance));
        }
    }

    private static <T> Optional<Method> resolveMethod(Class<T> aClass) {
        return Stream.of(aClass.getMethods())
                .filter(aMethod -> Modifier.isStatic(aMethod.getModifiers()))
                .filter(aMethod -> aMethod.getParameterCount() == 0)
                .findAny();
    }

    private static <U> void doSomething(Class<U> aClass, U anInstance) {
        // E.g. Map aClass to anInstance.
    }
}
```

The problem here, is that `doSomething` needs to be called with `Class<U>, U`, but it is currently being called with `Class<capture of ?>, capture of ?` due to the `invoke` method's wildcard return type.

I could change `doSomething` to `doSomething(Class<?> aClass, Object anInstance)` but then I lose the type safety and this is not necessarily the only place that method is called.

**My question is**: Why can the compiler not infer they have the same underlying type, `U`, given the explicit cast?

---

Edit (09 Mar 2021):

I went through the liberty of decompiling the byte code in order to see why [rzwitserloot's helper method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66556406/15362848) does indeed resolve the type problem.  They seem to be identical calls due to type erasure. I guess that the compiler is just not smart enough to infer they are the same capture type after the cast and needs the type-binding to help.

I've added the following functions

```
private static <U> void doSomethingWithTypeBinding(Class<U> aClass, Object anObject) {
    doSomething(aClass, aClass.cast(anObject));
}

private static void doSomethingUnsafe(Class<?> aClass, Object anInstance) {}
```

which I call from lines 15 and 16 respectively now

```
doSomethingWithTypeBinding(myMethod.getReturnType(), myInstance);
doSomethingUnsafe(myMethod.getReturnType(), myMethod.getReturnType().cast(myInstance));
```

Resulting in the following bytecode:

```
L5
    LINENUMBER 15 L5
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/reflect/Method.getReturnType ()Ljava/lang/Class;
    ALOAD 3
    INVOKESTATIC depinjection/handspun/services/MinimalExample.doSomethingWithTypeBinding (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
L6
    LINENUMBER 16 L6
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/reflect/Method.getReturnType ()Ljava/lang/Class;
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/reflect/Method.getReturnType ()Ljava/lang/Class;
    ALOAD 3
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Class.cast (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    INVOKESTATIC depinjection/handspun/services/MinimalExample.doSomethingUnsafe (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

// access flags 0xA
// signature <U:Ljava/lang/Object;>(Ljava/lang/Class<TU;>;TU;)V
// declaration: void doSomething<U>(java.lang.Class<U>, U)
private static doSomething(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    L0
        LINENUMBER 30 L0
        RETURN
    L1
        LOCALVARIABLE aClass Ljava/lang/Class; L0 L1 0
        // signature Ljava/lang/Class<TU;>;
        // declaration: aClass extends java.lang.Class<U>
        LOCALVARIABLE anInstance Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L1 1
        // signature TU;
        // declaration: anInstance extends U
        MAXSTACK = 0
        MAXLOCALS = 2

// access flags 0xA
// signature <U:Ljava/lang/Object;>(Ljava/lang/Class<TU;>;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
// declaration: void doSomethingWithTypeBinding<U>(java.lang.Class<U>, java.lang.Object)
private static doSomethingWithTypeBinding(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    L0
        LINENUMBER 33 L0
        ALOAD 0
        ALOAD 0
        ALOAD 1
        INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Class.cast (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        INVOKESTATIC depinjection/handspun/services/MinimalExample.doSomething (Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    L1
        LINENUMBER 34 L1
        RETURN
    L2
        LOCALVARIABLE aClass Ljava/lang/Class; L0 L2 0
        // signature Ljava/lang/Class<TU;>;
        // declaration: aClass extends java.lang.Class<U>
        LOCALVARIABLE anObject Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L2 1
        MAXSTACK = 3
        MAXLOCALS = 2

// access flags 0xA
// signature (Ljava/lang/Class<*>;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
// declaration: void doSomethingUnsafe(java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.Object)
private static doSomethingUnsafe(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    L0
        LINENUMBER 37 L0
        RETURN
    L1
        LOCALVARIABLE aClass Ljava/lang/Class; L0 L1 0
        // signature Ljava/lang/Class<*>;
        // declaration: aClass extends java.lang.Class<?>
        LOCALVARIABLE anInstance Ljava/lang/Object; L0 L1 1
        MAXSTACK = 0
        MAXLOCALS = 2
```

We can see the `INVOKEVIRTUAL` cast right into the `INVOKESTATIC` look identical due to their runtime type erasure.

---

Edit (12 Mar 2021):

@Holger [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66552153/java-reflection-casting-method-returntype/66556406?noredirect=1#comment117711430_66556406), `Method#getReturnType` returns a `Class<?>`. Because it is wildcarded, the method, from the compiler's point-of-view, has no guarantee of subsequent method calls returning a Class with the same capture type.

Comment: Side notes: the `<T>` type parameters of `invokeMethod` and `resolveMethod` are pointless. You can change the parameter types of the methods to `Class<?>` and remove the type parameter without changing the logic. Further, you can just use `resolveMethod(aClass).ifPresent(myMethod -> helper(myMethod.getReturnType(), myMethod.invoke(null));` instead of `isPresent()` and `get()` and the other intermediate steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type variables are a figment of the compiler's imagination: They don't survive compilation (erasure*). It is best to think about them as **linking things**. A type variable that is used in only one place, ever, is completely useless; once they show up in two places, now that's useful: It lets you link multiple usages of types together, to say that occurences are the same. For example, you can tie the parameter type of `.add(Obj thingToAdd)`, and the return type of `.get(int idx)` together for `java.util.List`.

Here, you want to link the `Class<X>` of `myMethod.getReturnType` together with the `myInstance` variable. As you realized, this is impossible, as the compiler doesn't *know* that they're going to end up being the same type. However, by invoking the `cast()` method of `Class<X>`, we work around that part.

But you still need *some type variable* to serve as vehicle to tie things together, and you don't have one. `?` is analogous to a one-use-and-done type variable; `Class<?> cls` and myMethod.getReturnType().cast(myInstance)` are 'different' ?s: Yes, your eyeballs can tell it's going to be the same type, but java can't. You need a type variable.  You can introduce one, of course:

```
private static <X> helper(Class<X> x, Object myInstance) {
    doSomething(x, x.cast(myInstance));
}
```

Add this method to your code and invoke this one, instead of invoking `doSomething`. The `<X>` that we created here serves to tie the results together.

*) They remain in public signatures, of course, but everywhere else, at runtime - they are erased.

An alternative option is available to you here: The `doSomething` method is *private*, so you are in full control of it. Therefore, you can either just move the cast inside it, which solves all problems, or, you write it like so:

```
/** precondition: o must be an instance of c */
private static void doSomething(Class<?> c, Object o) {
}
```

As it is a private method, preconditions are fine to introduce. You are in complete control of all code that invokes this method. If you really want to, you can add a runtime check (`if (!c.isInstanceof(o)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("o not instance of c");` at the top), but whether it is worth doing is an open debate in java ecosystems for private methods. Usually the verdict is not to do that, or to use an `assert` keyword for it.

NB: This has some atrocious null/optional handling. In case the method to be resolved isn't found you.. just silently do nothing? This is why NPEs are better: At least then careless coding results in an exception instead of a wild goose chase.

Comment: I think this gave a really great overview of why they are "different" captures; however, I'm still not 100% convinced why a compiler cannot resolve that they are the same after the `myMethod.getReturnType().cast(myInstance)` call. The helper method does this same thing just after binding the wildcard to a type afterall

Comment: And yes as noted, I own all of this code, so I could indeed just reduce the type-safety of `doSomething` and ensure it upstream or in preconditions, but I wanted to understand why the compiler cannot infer that they are the same types. Also this is not the actual code, but just a small working minimal example. The real dependency injector doesn't operate over optionals or filter by no-arg factories, but finds all annotated provider methods and has robust null handling :)

Comment: @AndoniMichael to the compiler, `getReturnType()` is just a method. It doesn’t know that its contract guarantees to return the same `Class` object on both invocations. Besides that, it just follows the rules.

Comment: @Holger Woah I hadn't thought about that. Because it returns a `Class<?>`, it is not guaranteed to return the same capture. Makes a ton of sense in that light! Will update the description.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the invocation is :

```
Object myInstance = myMethod.invoke(null);
```

`myMethod` is `static` (as you already found in `resolveMethod`), so you need to pass a `null`, otherwise you would need an instance for that, which you do not have.

And then fixing your example, is fairly trivial:

```
Method myMethod = myOptMethod.get();
Object myInstance = myMethod.invoke(null);

Class<?> cls = myMethod.getReturnType();
Object obj = myMethod.getReturnType().cast(myInstance);

doSomething(cls, obj);
```

where that method changes the definition to:

```
 private static <U> void doSomething(Class<? extends U> aClass, U anInstance) {....}
```

Comment: This is misleading; U will always bind the object and gives absolutely no type safety because 'Object' always works out. Therefore this code is a lie (it suggests safety where none exists), and would be better written as: `private static void doSomething(Class<?> c, Object instance) {}`. Now it's clear, and works just as well.

Comment: @rzwitserloot yes, this has no type safety, but I assume OP understands that already. Sometimes, though, you do want to capture wildcards, exactly why such methods exist.

Comment: As I said, `U` will always be object, so this doesn't capture anything useful. My suggestion is a strict improvement in that sense.

Comment: Yes, I noted the same solution in my question, but that reduces the type safety of the `doSomething` method. This isn't the only use case and I want to ensure that `anInstance` is indeed a type of `aClass`. The question was more about why the compiler cannot infer that they are the same type given the cast works.

Comment: Also thanks for the `invoke(null)` tip! The code works as is, but null is probably a better value. From the JavaDocs:

`If the underlying method is static, then the specified {@code obj} argument is ignored. It may be null.`